# libcurl compress downloaded data on the fly

Tags: c, linux, libcurl

Linux. I'm downloading a lot of data via libcurl. A data has low entropy but huge size (Tens of Gb). At the moment I first download file and then compress it with zlib.
But this takes more time and more space. So I'm trying to implement compress on the fly in libcurl write callback.
The main problem is exact size of data to download is unknown. The code is dirty but its just a test. And it seems this is not a way to go. Maybe some other way is more suitable?

```
unsigned char *outZ=malloc(1500);//Maximum write chunk is 1448
...
size_t
curl_write_func(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{   
    size_t data=zip(ptr,size*nmemb,outZ,1500,Z_FINISH);    
    fwrite(outZ, 1, data, (FILE *) stream); 
    return (size*nmemb);
}

size_t
zip(void *source, size_t src_size, void *target,size_t tgt_size, int mode)
{   
    z_stream strm;          
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    deflateInit(&strm, Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);
    strm.next_in = source;
    strm.avail_in = src_size;
    strm.next_out=target;
    strm.avail_out=tgt_size;
    deflate(&strm, mode);
    deflateEnd(&strm);
    return (tgt_size - strm.avail_out);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you control what happens server-side?

If yes, what about asking for already GZIP-ed content while turning off content decoding on libcurl side? Here is how to proceed (from a recent discussion on the mailing list): [request encoding without decoding](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2013-02/0241.html).

Otherwise a library such as [libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/) - that provides streaming capabilities, fed in a streaming manner (e.g. a la [HTML streaming parser with libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/href_extractor.html)) should do the trick.

--

**Update**: here's a sample code using on-the-fly compression with [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/): https://github.com/deltheil/zurl.

Comment: no, can control the server. it is XCP host, that can export virtual machines through HTTP PUT.  I'll try to look in libarchive, but one question: I need to create header first, but total file size is unknown... and the archives is corrupted if I write header after all

Comment: The [Zip and Streaming Writes](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/FormatZip#zip-and-streaming-writes) documentation section contains all the details - in particular, *[t]he Zip [streaming] writer accumulates the central directory information in memory and writes it out when the archive is closed*.

Answer (score 1):

At last I made it work with native zlib library
It may be not elegant enough, but my C skills are poor at the moment
Some variables are have to be global as zlib stream should be uninterrupted.
I compress the previous block as the last one should be flushed and I didn't find a way to determinate it via libcurl calls.
So if we out of easy_perform the previous ine was the last :)
All error checking are omitted for clarity
SHA1 checksum of *original* stream is calculated also

```
#define CHUNK 16384
SHA_CTX ctx;
z_stream strm;
unsigned char old_block[CHUNK];
unsigned char out[CHUNK];
unsigned have;
size_t prevBlkSize;
char firstIter;

size_t
curl_write_func(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    //Stores the size of original data to write
    size_t orig_size=size*nmemb;
    if(firstIter)
    {
        memcpy(old_block,ptr,orig_size);
        prevBlkSize=orig_size;
        firstIter=0;
        SHA1_Update(&ctx, ptr, orig_size);
        return(orig_size);
    }
    //Compress old block with Z_NO_FLUSH

    strm.avail_in=prevBlkSize;
    strm.next_in = old_block;
    do
    {
        strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
        strm.next_out = out;
        deflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
        have = CHUNK - strm.avail_out;
        fwrite(out, 1, have, (FILE *) stream);
    }
    while (strm.avail_out == 0);
    //

    memcpy(old_block,ptr,orig_size);
    prevBlkSize=orig_size;
    SHA1_Update(&ctx, ptr, orig_size);
    return (orig_size);
}
...
FILE *xva_export = fopen(xva_name, "wb");
//Prepare SHA1 and zlib
strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
deflateInit(&strm, 9);
SHA1_Init(&ctx);
...
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_write_func);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, xva_export);
curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
//Finish zlib
strm.avail_in=prevBlkSize;
strm.next_in = old_block;
do
{
    strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
    strm.next_out = out;
    deflate(&strm, Z_FINISH);
    have = CHUNK - strm.avail_out;
    fwrite(out, 1, have, xva_export);
}
while (strm.avail_out == 0);
deflateEnd(&strm);
//SHA1 finish
SHA1_Final(hash, &ctx);
snprintf(sha1_name,sizeof(sha1_name),"%s.Z.sha1",xva_name);
FILE *sha1sum=fopen(sha1_name,"w");
for(int i=0; i<SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
{
    fprintf(sha1sum,"%x",hash[i]);
}
fclose(sha1sum);
fclose(xva_export);
```

Comment: Well done! That being said you can avoid using globals: all you need to do is to maintain the current state (the zlib stream, output file handle, etc) within a dedicated structure that you simply need to pass as libcurl write data. I've written a tiny exemple that illustrates this: https://github.com/deltheil/zurl